# lru caching not working between application runs for same argument on Flask App

Tags: python, flask, caching, lru

*Edit: just realized I made a mistake in my function design where I re-instantiated the `AppDAO` in my `Class1` function and that is what was causing the unexpected behavior. I figured it out by printing the `self` argument in `cache_call`.

I have a Flask App with the following design:

```
 from flask import Flask, request
 from Class1 import Class1
 from AppDAO import AppDAO
 
 app = Flask(__name__)

 def main():
   app.config['appDAO'] = AppDAO()
   app.run()

 @app.route('/app_route1',methods=['POST'])
 def app_route1():
     print("Running app route 1...")
     print(app.config['appDAO'].cache_call.cache_info())
     
     cache_param = request.json.get('cached_parameter')
     print("The cached parameter is: %s." % cache_param)

     class1 = Class1(app.config['appDAO'])

     for item in ['item1', 'item2']:
           class1.do_processing(item,cache_param)
```

`Class1.py`:

```
class Class1(object):
   def __init__(self, app_dao):
     self.app_dao = app_dao

   def do_processing(self, item, cache_param):
        print("Processing for item: %s..." % item)

        resp_cache = self.app_dao.cache_call(cache_param)
        print(self.app_dao.cache_call.cache_info())
        
        return resp_cache
```

`AppDAO.py`:

```
from functools import lru_cache
import mysql.connector 

class AppDAO(object):
  
  def __init__():
      self.conn = mysql.connector.connect('user1','password1','server1','database')
  
  @lru_cache(maxsize=4)
  def cache_call(self, cache_param):
     print("Running cache call with parameter: %s..." % cache_param)

     cursor = self.conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = `%s`;" % cache_param)
     rs = cursor.fetchall()

     return rs
```

If I run the app making a post, the `AppDAO.cache_call` functions correctly with the following output `print` output:

```
 Running app route 1...
 CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=0, maxsize=4, currsize=0)
 Processing items: item1...
 Running cache call with parameter: foo1...
 CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=4, currsize=1)
 Processing items: item2...
 CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=4, currsize=1)
```

But I make another post to the branch using the same parameter for the `cache_call`, I get the following `print` output:

```
 Running app route 1...
 CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=4, currsize=1)
 Processing items: item1...
 Running cache call with parameter: foo1...
 CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=2, maxsize=4, currsize=2)
 Processing items: item2...
 CacheInfo(hits=2, misses=2, maxsize=4, currsize=2)
```

I run the app using the `Anaconda QT Console`, but I experience the following caching issue if I used an `Anaconda Command Prompt` as well. Can anyone speculate why the `lru_cache` is not working when a new post is made to the app despite the cached call still clearing being stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=4)
def cache_call(self, cache_param):
```

is wrapping a method, not a function. In your example, `self`, which will be used as as part of the cache key, is an instance of `Class1` <strike>and is created once per route handler invocation. The result is that you aren't getting the caching you expect</strike>.

**Updated:** I misread the code. Assuming that

```
for item in [item1, item2]:
```

was a typo, and should be

```
for item in ['item1', 'item2']:
```

and that you're `do_processing` is intentionally not passing `item` (which varies) to `cache_call`, then what you're seeing is consistent with how `lru_cache` behaves.

On first request, it's going to add one thing (`request.json.get('cached_parameter')`) to the cache, scoring it as a miss the for 'item1' and a hit for 'item2'.

On second request, `request.json.get('cached_parameter')` is a different object. It gets scored as a miss for 'item1', added (increasing 'currsize' to 2). For 'item2', it gets scored as a hit.

What behavior did you expect?

Unrelated but worth mentioning: The way you're constructing that query leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks. Consider using a bind parameter instead.

Comment: I am using the same `AppDAO` object that is instantiated in the Flask app `main` function only once when the application is first started. Why would re-instantiating the `Class1` object affect the cache for `AppDAO`?

Comment: Oops. Misread that. Updated analysis above.

Comment: @davidism If you're going to close this as relating to thread safety, please leave a hint as to why/where that applies here. The issue at hand is the behavior of an lru cache in the presence of _serial_ requests.

Comment: Actually I figured out the problem, it was that I was re-instantating the `AppDAO` because `Class1` was designed differently than the other Classes in my app routes. I figured it out by printing the `self` argument in the cached call.